# how to properly include fusioncharts.js into node express project using jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried

`script(src="/fusioncharts.charts.js")`

in the head of layout.jade, but it didnt work, error 404.

Then I tried via

layout.jade:
`script(src="/charts")`

app.js:
`app.get('/charts', routes.charts);`

index.js:

```
exports.charts = function(req, res){
res.sendFile(__dirname + "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts.js");
};
```

I get error : res.sendFile is not a function.

I have enide2015, project created with node_modules from enide.

I tried with  -- router.get( ... - I got property undefined error

layout.jade:

```
doctype html
html( lang="en" )
head
title= title
meta( charset='utf-8' )
meta( http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge' )
meta( name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' )
meta( name='description', content='Baking Bootstrap Snippets with Jade' )
//- Bootswatch Theme
link(href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch
/3.3.6/flatly/bootstrap.min.css',rel='stylesheet')
script(src="https://www.google.com/jsapi")
script(src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true")
script(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js')
script(src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js')
//***************************
script(src="/fusioncharts")
//***************************
```

In other words, proper way to include external js local library, not CDN source ,ideally specifically fusioncharts ?  Thank you.

EDIT: OK, found the problem, when creating node express project with Enide, there's pre-set environment in app.js, setting only PUBLIC folder accessible. I got now 200 OK message while accessing fusioncharts.js file.
I am still not able to render the chart itself, rendering ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Found this trending on Reddit - talks about using FusionCharts with Node, Express and MongoDB.

http://www.fusioncharts.com/tutorials/creating-interactive-charts-using-node-express-and-mongodb/